# Tokenizing a string having double quotes

Tags: python-2.7, nlp, nltk

I have a string in the form :

```
'I am going to visit "Huge Hotel" and the "Grand River"'
```

I want it tokenized as

```
['I', 'am', 'going',..., 'Huge Hotel','and' ,'the' ,'Grand River']
```

As seen *'Huge Hotel'* and *'Grand River'* are taken as a single word as they were present in quotes.

```
import nltk
text = 'I am going to visit "Huge Hotel" and the "Grand River"'
b = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
```

I have written above code but it does'nt work

Comment: It'd be better if you show what have you tried. Right now, this is just _Right code for me_ which most likely won't welcomed here.

Comment: Just updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks odd but it works:

1. `re.findall('"([^"]*)"', s)`: Find all substrings enclosed in double quotes
2. `phrase.replace(' ', '_')`: Replace all spaces with underscore in these substrings from Step 1.
3. Replace all the strings enclosed in double quotes with the underscored substrings from Step 2.
4. Use `word_tokenize()` on the modified string.

[out]:

```
>>> import re
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> s = 'I am going to visit "Huge Hotel" and the "Grand River"'
>>> for phrase in re.findall('"([^"]*)"', s):
...     s = s.replace('"{}"'.format(phrase), phrase.replace(' ', '_'))
... 
>>> s
'I am going to visit Huge_Hotel and the Grand_River'
>>> word_tokenize(s)
['I', 'am', 'going', 'to', 'visit', 'Huge_Hotel', 'and', 'the', 'Grand_River']
```

I'm sure there's a simpler regex operation that can replace the series of regex + string operations.

Comment: Thanks for the help,  but you have used an underscore (_) is there a way to do the same with out the underscore ????

Comment: Nope, it's rather hard to protect phrases with `word_tokenize`, underscore is one of the few chars that will protect the phrases from tokenization.

Comment: @Saul_goodman I would recommend you to try `pos` tagging the sentence, but that too is rather hard.